# How do I map one range of values to another in python

Tags: python, dictionary, int, byte

Want to do the equivalent of this, (and the inverse toByte) in python, how do you map in python?

```
int toInt(byte b) {
  return map(b, 0, 255, -128, 127);
}
```

i would try

```
int([representation],base)-128
```

but I don't know what representation and base are

Comment: What's the output supposed to be?

Comment: What is the original language here?

Comment: Are you meaning "map a value in the range [0:256] to a value in the range [-128:128]"? That would be mapping an unsigned byte (`uint8`) to a signed byte (`int8`)?

Comment: c++ (arduino). the input is a value from 0 to 255, the output is the value in the range -128 to 127 with the equivalent position

Answer (score 3):

`int([representation],base)-128` If I understood well your question.
If you for whatever reason you are not happy with a function, try using a python dictionary structure

Comment: anyone know what representation and base are?

Comment: representation is the way you write the value of your byte. representation='11111111' and base=2 would return you 255. You could also have your bite in hexadecimal, it depends where it comes from in your code.

Answer (score 0):

There's more than one way to do it.  You could use an explicit mapping:

```
INT_MAP = {x: x - 128 for x in range(256)}
def to_int(val):
    """Maps an unsigned integer to a signed one (for values up to 256)"""
    try:
        return INT_MAP[val]
    except KeyError:
        raise ValueError("val must be a value between 0 and 255")
```

Alternately, you could use math:

```
def to_int(val, max_signed_val=128):
    max_val = max_signed_val * 2
    assert val < max_val, "val must be less than {:d}".format(max_val)
    return val - max_signed_val
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't that simply be:

```
def toInt(b):
    return b-128

def toByte(i):
    return i+128
```